Swift parameter packs and Sendable
The following code produces a warning about a non-sendable type:
func pack<each U: Sendable>(arg: repeat each U, function: @escaping @Sendable (repeat each U) -> Void) {
    Task { @MainActor in
        function(repeat each arg)
    }
}

Warning:
Capture of 'arg' with non-sendable type 'repeat each U' in a @Sendable closure
The types 'U' were marked as Sendable, but the compiler does not seem to see this.
Is this a compiler bug, or I am doing something wrong?

This might be an oversight instead of a bug. The documentation for Sendable doesn't say that value packs are Sendable at all, so technically this is correct according to the documentation. It is likely that they just didn't consider this when designing the two features.
As a workaround, tuples are Sendable, so if you wrap the arg parameter in a tuple, it compiles without warnings.
func pack<each U: Sendable>(arg: repeat each U, function: @escaping @Sendable (repeat each U) -> Void) {
    let tuple = (repeat each arg)
    Task { @MainActor in
        function(repeat each tuple)
    }
}


Unfortunately this requires me to alter the passed function argument, which forces all the users to wrap their arguments in a tuple. The idea is to replace 20+ semi-identical functions with just one function taking a parameter pack, so that callers would not need to change anything...

@SergeyA.Novitsky I just realised that you don't actually need to change the type of arg. Just make a tuple before running the Task.

Unfortunately this does not make the warning go away (Xcode 15.4).

I have also created a bug report for Swift: https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/74392

@SergeyA.Novitsky Okay, I cannot reproduce on Xcode 15.3. At the end of the day though, I don't think you should worry about it too much.

The example given in the original question compiles without warnings or errors in Xcode 16.1.
However, the following example does still trigger the error in Xcode 16.1:
struct T<V>: Sendable {
    let f: @Sendable () -> V
}

func zip<each V>(_ t: repeat T<each V>) -> T<(repeat each V)> {
    return T { (repeat (each t).f()) }
                          // ^  Capture of 't' with non-sendable type 'repeat T<each V>' in a `@Sendable` closure
}

Copying the variadic argument into a local tuple (as suggested by Sweeper) seems to work around the error:
func zip<each V>(_ t: repeat T<each V>) -> T<(repeat each V)> {
    // Copying t to a local variable eliminates the error.
    let t = (repeat each t)
    return T { (repeat (each t).f()) }
}

